# Ants everywhere in the bathroom

Tags: bathroom, ants

I don't know if this question belongs here but I can't find anywhere else to put it.

In recent weeks, ants have decided to move into my bathroom. At first, there were a couple in the shower stall and I would just wash them down. Last week, they started to appear in more and more numbers. It isn't apparent what they are going after as there is nothing in the bathroom. After constantly washing them down the drain, they are now avoiding the shower stall and crowding all around the shower stall and just piling up, doing nothing. It may be that they are building a nest there but why in such an open place? Anyways, I'm just asking for how to get rid of them safely so that they won't return again.

I haven't used any bug sprays to try and get rid of them as I don't feel comfortable using that in my bathroom.

I'm in Australia and these are tiny black ants if it helps.

Comment: I'd like to (not really) see a picture of all the cracks in the grout, one of which behind is where they live or are trying to.

Comment: My experience (in the US, East Coast) is that the tiny black ants we get inside the house almost always are coming from a nest outside, somewhere, like in landscaping.  They're coming into the house looking for food to take back to the nest.

Comment: just eradicate them with boric acid; cheap, easy, effective AF.

Comment: @SteveSh That's what I thought. There might be a nest right on the other side of the mirror.

Comment: @nitsua60 ummm, I wouldn't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ants need two things, food and water.  Often their normal source of water may dry up due to weather and they will seek out new sources of it.  It sounds like your bathroom has met their requirements and they are invading.

While you can try some remedies available to consumers you may want to bring in a professional exterminator.  They will track down where they are entering and abate them there.

Comment: It is winter in Australia so I'm not sure if water is the problem although I'm not saying that it can't be.

Comment: It could also be food, perhaps there is some rotting wood or other material that they are feeding on.  There is something, however, in your bathroom that is attracting them.